# 70s - 80s movie scifi post apocalyptic action lone fighter

Tags: story-identification, movie

The signature thing describing the protagonist is that he has built in his hand a device that can retrieve his gun which was lost in a fight or taken by an enemy.  Normally the device is not visible but when used, it appears like a glowing circle on the hand's inner side.

Comment: Not a great question (lacking detail) but certainly not worthy of closure.

Comment: Do you know what language and/or country the movie is from?  Any other details you 
remember about the movie would help greatly.

Comment: I think its US/UK, language english, somewhat mix of mad max 1, totall recall 1, and maybe a bit of hell goes to frogtown, there was also involdved some kind of flying machine that goes on scifi fuel, not sure if there were involved interplanetary travel though